# how can I troubleshoot "rake test" missing from my list of rake tasks?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, rake

I have two apps. One is a very simple app that I built with `rails new...`, added a unit test to and ran the unit test. The other is an existing app that is running fine but I'd like to add some tests to it. In AppA (the simple one) when I run `rake -vT` I see:

```
...
rake test               # Runs test:units, test:functionals, test:integrati...
rake test:recent        # Run tests for {:recent=>"test:prepare"} / Test re...
rake test:single        # Run tests for {:single=>"test:prepare"}
rake test:uncommitted   # Run tests for {:uncommitted=>"test:prepare"} / Te...
...
```

Which seems normal. But when I run that same command in AppB (the existing app) I don't see any of the commands related to `rake test`. My first thought was to just 'bring over' the tests from AppA to AppB to see if that would help. So I wiped all content from the test directory in AppB and copied over the test directory from AppA. Still no `rake test` in the list of apps. But I can run a unit test in AppB via `ruby -Itest test/unit/first_test.rb` (oddly I have to comment out `fixtures :all` to get it to work, maybe that's a clue).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the answer to this last night. Where a new app's application.rb has:

```
  require 'rails/all'
```

I had:

```
  require "action_controller/railtie"
  require "action_mailer/railtie"
  require "active_resource/railtie"
  require "sprockets/railtie"
  require "rails/test_unit/railtie"
```

I did that because I was following a guide about MongoMapper I think. Go forward a few versions and the last line is commented out -- that's the real reason. I commented it out at the same time I switched my ODM over to Mongoid. I'm not sure why I commented it out, but that definitely did it.

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing the contents of your `Rakefile` it's really hard to debug this, but you might be missing the `.load_tasks` call in the `Rakefile`.

If you're using Rails 3 you should have something like this:

```
MyApplication::Application.load_tasks
```

That line will take care of loading the default Rails tasks. You might be able to accomplish the same calling `require "rails/tasks"` in your `Rakefile`.

Comment: Thanks for taking a shot. Doesn't look like that was it though. The rakefile has `require File.expand_path('../config/application', __FILE__)

TheApp::Application.load_tasks
`

Comment: Not sure of what's going on then, but you can try to add `load "rails/test_unit/testing.rake"` to your Rakefile, that should give you the test tasks.